# Increase one by one php variable in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table. The table have id, name and sname columns. I want to run a sql query in php. For example my query is

```
Select * from mytable where id=$n;
```

Here $n is a variable first value is 1. When the page is loaded this query is running. I listed a table query result. I want to increase $n value with a html button. The button is clicked $n value must be 2 and query must execute with new $n variable.

Comment: The PHP isn't available once the page has loaded. You could use AJAX or a `form` and run it with the updated on the reload.

Comment: Yes @chris85 right. and please add more codes to your question.

Comment: Just send $n+1 to a script, like /script.php?n=5, then script should check if it exists and put it into sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post with a form and increment the id

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["increment"]) && $_GET["increment"] == 1)
   $n++;

$sql = "Select * from mytable where id=$n;";

// display data as usual

?>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="increment" value="1"/>
    <button type="submit">increment</button>
</form>
```

Comment: $n will always be 1 with this approach.

Comment: @chris85 You mean it will always be 2? OP doesn't specify more on how `$n` is set

Comment: Well `$n` is not initialized so it is `0` when you hit the  `$n++` it is doing `0 + 1`. https://eval.in/583682

Comment: @chris85 `$n` must be initialized if it's returning results. I suppose id could be 0, but question says it's 1

Comment: Oh, this is additional code to the OPs. Well the incrementing will only happen once. All subsequent increments will be row 2.

Comment: @chris85 that's right. I hope the mechanism is demonstrated clearly enough that OP can apply it to whatever process used to initialize `$n`

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to make an Ajax request instead.

On each click of the button increment some Javascript variable. This variable can be passed to the script via AJAX.

Comment: If you don't have a solution please don't post an answer.

Comment: @IvanBarayev how is this not a solution?

Comment: Try to read comments under the question, one friend said same. If you want to see a solution lease look at new answer.

Comment: The page has loaded firstly it will run this query:Select * from mytable where id=$n;. Later the button is clicked. I have to send a ajax request to for example ajax.php. What should I send to ajax.php? Later when I get sending value how can I change $n variable value?. Sorry I am new.

Comment: Look at other answer as it should allow you to maintain your $n variable anyway you'd like